# Uneven edges and glitches where 3D objects meet

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx

I'm diving right into my first 3D game by trying to convert a tile based game to a 3D one. I'm using libGDX's new 3D classes to accomplish this.

Each block in a tile map will be converted to a 3D object in this case I'm rendering each tile as a box. It works reasonably well but I'm getting graphical errors where boxes share an edge or corner.

This seems to work better on the desktop project (It seems to occur sometimes but less severe):

[image: Desktop Rendering]

But not on android devices:
[image: Android Rendering]

This glitching varies depending on where on the screen the block is drawn. This occurs on several different android devices but more noticeable on those with higher screen resolutions.

Here is the code I'm using to render it in the main libGDX project:

```
    @Override
public void create() {      
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    instances = new ArrayList<ModelInstance>();

    //Setup camera
    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(0, 0, 150f);
    cam.lookAt(0, 0,0);
    cam.near = 0.1f;
    cam.far = 500f;
    cam.update();

    //Setup Lighting
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

    // Add boxes
    addBox(new Vector3(-50,0,0));
    addBox(new Vector3(-50,16,0));
    addBox(new Vector3(-50,32,0));
    addBox(new Vector3(-50,48,0));

    addBox(new Vector3(50,48,0));
    addBox(new Vector3(66,48,0));
    addBox(new Vector3(82,48,0));
    addBox(new Vector3(98,48,0));

}

private void addBox(Vector3 position){
    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    Model model = modelBuilder.createBox(16f, 16f, 16f, 
            new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
            Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
    ModelInstance mis = new ModelInstance(model);
    mis.transform.setTranslation(position);
    instances.add(mis);
}


@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

//          The next two lines seem to improve the problem. Problem is almost totally gone
//          I tweaked the values in glPolygonOffset to make it work better
            Gdx.gl20.glEnable(Gdx.gl20.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
            Gdx.gl20.glPolygonOffset(0.1f,0.1f);

//          These make it worse!
//              Gdx.gl.glEnable(Gdx.gl20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
//              Gdx.gl20.glDepthFunc(Gdx.gl20.GL_LEQUAL); // GL_LESS is default


    modelBatch.begin(cam);

    for(ModelInstance mi : instances)
        modelBatch.render(mi,environment);

    modelBatch.end();
}
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

Render on phone after changes to render() method (zoomed in, less bad edges):
[image: Android Rendering after]

Comment: The problem is occurring because the blocks are so close together.

If you see these marks flickering, the renderer thinks the blocks are overlapping a little bit, so it isn't sure which triangle to draw (and so switches back and forth between the two equal possibilities).

If the marks don't flicker, the renderer thinks there needs to be a tiny shadow cast there by the adjacent block.

Someone else would have to suggest how to go about fixing this in regards to Java: maybe something with RenderingHints can help if you are using Java 7.

Comment: Looks like rasterizer sub-pixel precision issues. GL and GL ES implementations have different minimum values for sub-pixel precision. [*Sometimes*](http://abepralle.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/iphone-2d-projection-matrix-fpu/) doing the math to generate your transformation matrices at higher precision can help to avoid these issues. GL will still use single-precision for the matrices during transformation, but you might avoid some inaccuracies during the initial calculation of the matrix.

Answer (score 3):

The problem occuring when having two objects overlap at the exact same depth is called "stitching".

You can avoid it by using a [polygon depth offset](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter06.html#name4). It basically adds some extra depth to your drawn polygons. You might have to use a different value for that for every object that you want to render, which might overlap.

```
Gdx.gl.glEnable(Gdx.gl10.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
Gdx.gl10.glPolygonOffset(1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Sometimes adjusting the depth function might also help. We want to adjust it to also render the polygon when the depths is equal to the one which was already rendered before.

```
Gdx.gl.glEnable(Gdx.gl10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
Gdx.gl10.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL); // GL_LESS is default
```